# What is 'log4j.logger.com.sivalabs=DEBUG' in log4j properties file

Tags: log4j, properties-file

In our one of log4j properties file I can see below line:

***log4j.logger.com.sivalabs=DEBUG***

anyone has idea about what is this exactly?

Answer (score 6):

Looks like someone copy pasted code from my blog (sivalabs.in) and forgot to change the base package name "com.sivalabs". They are supposed to change it to their project package name.

Answer (score 0):

From https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html

> # Print only messages of level WARN or above in the package com.foo. 
> log4j.logger.com.foo=WARN

Therefore in your case, you are logging level DEBUG (or above) to package com.sivalabs

Comment: but we do not have any such package (com.sivalabs) in our project structure.

Comment: it could be a jar inside your project, otherwise you can remove it. The idea is to have there a java package that you want to log.